# Unable to validate role in Spring Security for url pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spelevaluationexception

I am using spring security 3.1.7.RELEASE with spring 3.2.13.RELEASE.

I have entry in my spring-security.xml as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
    <intercept-url pattern=".*admin.htm" access="hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/siteadmin/*.htm" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/siteadmin/cleancache.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

When I try to hit url /siteadmin/cleancache.htm I get following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression
>   'ROLE_ADMIN'
>     org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
>     org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
>
> Root Cause:
>
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_ADMIN' cannot be found on
>   object of type
>   'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
>   - maybe not public?   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:214)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>     org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
>     org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)

Any pointers on same are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have a couple of typos. The first intercept-url line is missing single quotes around ROLE_ADMIN and the second line is missing hasRole. It should be

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
    <intercept-url pattern=".*admin.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/siteadmin/*.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/siteadmin/cleancache.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Comment: Agreed reason being previously I was not using any expression which was working fine. So instead of changing whole xml in a go, I thought to first test this method with couple of URL and thats where I am facing this issue

Comment: No probs, I have done something similar in the past.

Comment: tarunkumar same problm, same soln for me also

Answer (score 6):

what happens is that the official documentation of security spring brings the examples as you placed:

```
<Intercept-url pattern = "/ siteadmin / *. Htm" access = "ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

but you should putting on

```
<Intercept-url pattern = ". * Admin.htm" access = "hasRole ('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam  Why would the spring documentation be wrong here ?

Comment: @JasonKrs I'm not the person post this answer, I just edited it.

Comment: @Rubens I have the same issue but you answer did not solve it. Why would the spring documentation be wrong here ?